# "Недопустимое имя столбца" при работе с sql запросом

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Имеется форма для добавления новой группы (скриншоты прилагаются чуть ниже). При нажатии на кнопку сохранения, происходит сохранение данной записи в таблицу tGroup (успешно). После сохранения, из tGroup должен браться id (первичный ключ) этой группы и передаваться в другую таблицу (вот тут и происходит ошибка в sql запросе).

```
void LoadIdGroup(string name)
        {
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID_Group from tGroups where sName="+name, connection);
            dtGroup = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dtGroup);
            bsGroup = new BindingSource();
            bsGroup.DataSource = dtGroup;
        }
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand commandInsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tGroups]" +
            " VALUES(@Name, @Count)", connection);
        commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbName.Text);
        commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count", tbCount.Text);
        commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand commandInsertRoutes = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tGroupsRoutes]" +
        " VALUES (@ID_Group, @ID_Route)", connection);
         commandInsertRoutes.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Route", Convert.ToInt32(cbRoutes.SelectedValue));
        LoadIdGroup(tbName.Text);
        commandInsertRoutes.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Group", Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)this.bsGroup.Current).Row["ID_Group"]));
        commandInsertRoutes.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам уже писали о параметризации SQL запросов. Серьезно подумайте об этом, тем более, что Вы ее (параметризацию) используете в соседнем методе.

---

В данном случае, однако, ошибка вызвана отсутствием одинарных кавычек вокруг значения `name` в:

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID_Group from tGroups where sName="+name, connection);
```

Поэтому сервер думает, что значение `name`, строка `"Группа"`, - это *название* поля в таблице.